# Maven-metadata.xml mismatch when deploying from Jenkins to Nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I'm using the Nexus plugin in Jenkins to publish an application to Nexus. I'm trying to make the pipeline publish the snapshot version.

The pipeline gives this error message:

Failed to deploy metadata: Could not transfer metadata group:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to group:artifact-snapshot (https://our-nexus-repo/group:artifact-snapshot): Failed to transfer file: https://our-nexus-repo/group:artifact-snapshot/group/artifact/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase:Invalid maven-metadata.xml GAV group, artifact, 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT does not match request path repository/group:artifact-snapshot/group/artifact/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.

I took a look at the .xml in Nexus and copied it into the repo which didn't have this .xml file before, and tried again. Same error message. I deleted the snapshot folder in Nexus and tried again, same error. I tried updating the snapshot version number, same error. I don't have access to any configuration in Nexus, and this is my first time around Jenkins. The group, artifact and version info in the pom is correct. Searching in here didn't solve it so far. Any ideas please?

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that you have a colon between group and artifact in your address: https://our-nexus-repo/group:artifact-snapshot. Did you make an error while replacing original address with the fake? Or do you actually have a colon there?

Comment: The 400 http code exactly shows something is wrong with your request....

Comment: How are you doing the push operation? It seems  to me you are using the Nexus Jenkins plugin and manually passing the GAV parameters and these might not match with what you have in pom.xml in your workspace

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Yes you are right, I made an error while doing the replacement.

Comment: @DanielHernández Initially the GAV parameters were only in the pom.xml and after this error kept repeating I tried to make a metadata.xml by copying the values from the one in Nexus. I checked that they matched the one in the pom

Answer (score 0):

I asked the Nexus admin to try this:
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-19943

Now I can deploy the snapshots, so it seems resolved. However the problem is I still don't understand what caused this error and whether it will mess up something later.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem, although how different this problem look, the solution is absolutely different.
I change the version of the build
from

```
0.0.11-snapshot
```

to

```
0.0.11-SNAPSHOT
```

Its all CAPS!
True Story!